# Curved hypotenuse of right triangle?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make a right triangle in which hypotenuse would be a curve drawn by one of the legs acting as a radius. Is there a better way to do this?

[shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To4ur.png)

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";
const p0 = { x: 0, y: 0  }
const p1 = { x: 80,  y: 20 }
const p2 = { x: 100,  y: 100  }

ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(p0.x, p0.y);
ctx.arcTo(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, 100);
ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
ctx.lineTo(0, 100)
ctx.lineTo(0, 0)
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: That's called a quarter circle. And this question is more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.quadrant {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius:0 100% 0 0;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="quadrant">
<div>
```

You can try to use [`border-radius` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).